# Can an NPC cast a spell with a higher-level spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, spellcasting, spell-slots

Can an NPC cast a spell with a higher-level spell slot?

For instance, an [Archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage) has a spell slot for 9th level spells, and knows the [Magic Missile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/magic-missile) spell.

As the DM, can I make my Archmage NPC cast Magic Missile with a 9th-level slot, creating 11 darts instead of just 3? Or is it only PCs that can cast spells with a higher-level spell slot?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Monsters can upcast spells just as characters can

The *Monster Manual*'s section on ["Spellcasting"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Spellcasting) states (page 10; emphasis mine):

> A monster with the Spellcasting class feature has a spellcaster level and spell slots, which it uses to cast its spells of 1st level and higher **(as explained in the *Player's Handbook*).** The spellcaster level is also used for any cantrips included in the feature.
>
> The monster has a list of spells known or prepared from a particular class. The list might also include spells from a feature in that class, such as the Divine Domain feature of the cleric or the Druid Circle feature of the druid. The monster is considered a member of that class when attuning to or using a magic item that requires member-ship in the class or access to its spell list.
>
> **A monster can cast a spell from its list at a higher level if it has the spell slot to do so.** For example, a drow mage with the 3rd-level *lightning bolt* spell can cast it as a 5th-level spell by using one of its 5th-level spell slots [...]

The first bolded section shows that monsters follow the usual spellcasting rules, and the second shows in particular that they can upcast spells into higher level slots that they possess.